# What to do about a logo image appearing after the page has loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, pageload

The logo image for my site appears after the page is loaded.

**Because of the way the image was designed to fit into the context of the page, it leaves a gaping hole in the appearance of the page.**

Is there a workaround for this maybe using JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: Why does the image appear after the page is loaded? I do not understand.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to explain better, but you might consider some of the following options:

1. Compress your image better
2. Find a better webhost if bandwidth
   is a bottleneck
3. Preloading wont help probably in
   this situation, if however you are using multiple images [preloading](http://elouai.com/javascript-preload-images.php) will help
4. Consider a placeholder image/div
   that lies underneath the logo (IE.
   please wait, logo loading, and the
   logo loads ontop with a higher
   z-index)
5. Consider a new page design if it is too resource intensive
6. Have a please wait loading message, this is probably going to put off your visitors though

If you provide a link to your website we can help more, the problem is too general to give and specifics.